# Elementary properties of diff. form from PMA Rudin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

[image]

How he got $d\omega$ in the RHS of $(39)$? Or maybe it's a typo?

Comment: It's a typo. Just an annoying typo.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Can you help please with this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753266/does-such-property-exist-for-differential-forms?