# Confusing moment in Theorem 10.27 from PMA Rudin

Tags: differential-forms

**Theorem 10.27** If $\sigma$ is an oriented rectilinear $k$-simplex in an open set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then $$\int \limits_{\overline{\sigma}}\omega=\varepsilon\int \limits_{\sigma}\omega \qquad (81)$$ for every $k$-form $\omega$ in $E$.

**Proof:** If $k=0$ then $0$-form is continuous function, namely $f$. Then RHS of $(81)$ is $\varepsilon\int \limits_{\sigma}f=\varepsilon^2f(\mathbf{p}_0)=f(\mathbf{p}_0).$ But LHS of $(81)$ is $\int \limits_{\overline{\sigma}}f=f(\mathbf{p}_0)$ since $\overline\sigma=\varepsilon \sigma=\varepsilon^2\mathbf{p}_0=\mathbf{p}_0.$(Here I just used the remark before theorem 10.27.)

Let's assume that $k\geqslant 1$ and $\sigma$ is given by $(75)$. Suppose $0<i<j\leqslant k$ and $\overline\sigma$ is obtained from $\sigma$ by intechanging $\mathbf{p}_i$ and $\mathbf{p}_j$ and in this case $\varepsilon=-1$. WLOG we can assume that $i=1$ and $j=2$.

Also by $(78)$ we have: $\sigma(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{p}_0+A\mathbf{u}$ where $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $A\mathbf{e}_i=\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_0$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant k$.

Also $\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{p}_0+C\mathbf{u}$ where $C$ has the columns as $A$, except that the $1$st and $2$nd columns have been interchanged.

Note that Rudin missed rigorous proof that $\int \limits_{\overline \sigma}\omega=\varepsilon \int \limits_{\sigma}\omega.$

Suppose that $\omega=f(\mathbf{x})dx_{i_1}\land \dots\land dx_{i_k}$ (we can consider this special case since general case follown from linearity).

$$\int \limits_{\overline \sigma}\omega=\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u}))\dfrac{\partial(\overline\sigma_{i_1},\dots,\overline\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial(u_1,\dots,u_k)}d\mathbf{u}\color\red{=}$$ It's easy to see that $\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u})=\sigma(B\mathbf{u})$ where $B$ is the flip operator which intechanges $1$st and $2$nd coordinates (definition 10.6). Note that $$\dfrac{\partial(\overline\sigma_{i_1},\dots,\overline\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial(u_1,\dots,u_k)}=-\dfrac{\partial(\sigma_{i_1},\dots,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial(u_1,\dots,u_k)}.$$ Hence $$\color\red{=}-\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\sigma(B\mathbf{u}))\dfrac{\partial(\sigma_{i_1},\dots,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial(u_1,\dots,u_k)}d\mathbf{u}=-\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\sigma(u_2,u_1,\dots,u_k))\dfrac{\partial(\sigma_{i_1},\dots,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial(u_1,\dots,u_k)}d\mathbf{u}=$$$$=\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\sigma(u_2,u_1,\dots,u_k))\dfrac{\partial(\sigma_{i_1},\dots,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial(u_2,u_1,\dots,u_k)}d\mathbf{u}$$
But the last integral is $\int \limits_{\sigma}\omega$ (Here I hidden use example 10.4 from PMA Rudin). Hence we get $\int \limits_{\overline\sigma}\omega=\int \limits_{\sigma}\omega$ but as you see before the second integral must be $\varepsilon=-1$.

Where I made mistake? Can you please help with this? I spent more than day but still can't find my mistake.

**Remark:** Note that there is also case when intechange vertices $\mathbf{p}_0$ and $\mathbf{p}_j$ for some $0<j\leqslant k$

**EDIT:** Let's consider the second case: Suppose that $0<i\leqslant k$ and $\overline \sigma=[\mathbf{p}_0,\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2,\dots,\mathbf{p}_k]$ is obtained from $\sigma$ by interchanging $\mathbf{p}_i$ and $\mathbf{p}_0$. WLOG we assume that $i=1$ and hence $\overline \sigma=[\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_0,\mathbf{p}_2,\dots,\mathbf{p}_k]$.

It's easy to check that $\overline \sigma(\mathbf{u})=\overline \sigma(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_k)=\sigma(1-\sum \limits_{l=1}^{k}u_l,u_2,\dots, u_k)=\sigma(G\mathbf{u})$ where $G$ is primitive mapping (see definition 10.5) with $m=1$ and $g(\mathbf{u})=1-\sum \limits_{l=1}^{k}u_l$.

We have to show that $\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\sigma(\mathbf{u}))d\mathbf{u}=\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u}))d\mathbf{u}$.

Suppose that $f_{k-1}(u_2,\dots,u_k)=\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(\sigma(\mathbf{u}))du_1$ and $\overline f_{k-1}(u_2,\dots,u_k)=\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u}))du_1$. If we prove that $f_{k-1}(u_2,\dots,u_k)=\overline f_{k-1}(u_2,\dots,u_k)$ then general problem follows immediately (+ example 10.4 from Rudin).

If $u_2+\dots+u_k>1$ then $\mathbf{u}\notin Q^k$ and $f_{k-1}=\overline f_{k-1}$ since integrand are zero.

If $S=u_2+\dots+u_k\leqslant 1$ then for $u_1>1-S$ integrand is zero hence $\int \limits_{0}^{1}=\int \limits_{0}^{1-S}$

Since $f_{k-1}(u_2,\dots,u_k)=\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(\sigma(\mathbf{u}))du_1=\int \limits_{0}^{1-S}f(\sigma(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_k))du_1$ if we regard the integrand as function of variable $u_1$ and making transform $g(u_1)=1-u_1-\sum \limits_{l=2}^{k}u_l$ (note that: $g(0)=1-S$ and $g(1-S)=0$) we get the following: $\int \limits_{0}^{1-S}f(\sigma(\mathbf{u}))du_1=\int \limits_{0}^{1-S}f(\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u}))du_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(\sigma(\mathbf{u}))du_1=\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u}))du_1$ and integrating we get $\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\sigma(\mathbf{u}))d\mathbf{u}=\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\overline\sigma(\mathbf{u}))d\mathbf{u}$.

Since Jacobians does not depend on $\mathbf{u}$ and reasoning in book shows that  $$\text{det}\begin{bmatrix}
D_1\sigma_{i_1} & D_2\sigma_{i_1}  \cdots & D_k\sigma_{i_1} \\
D_1\sigma_{i_2} & D_2\sigma_{i_2}  \cdots & D_k\sigma_{i_2} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
D_1\sigma_{i_k} & D_2\sigma_{i_k}  \cdots & D_k\sigma_{i_k} \\
\end{bmatrix}=-\text{det}\begin{bmatrix}
D_1\overline\sigma_{i_1} & D_2\overline\sigma_{i_1}  \cdots & D_k\overline\sigma_{i_1} \\
D_1\overline\sigma_{i_2} & D_2\overline\sigma_{i_2}  \cdots & D_k\overline\sigma_{i_2} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
D_1\overline\sigma_{i_k} & D_2\overline\sigma_{i_k}  \cdots & D_k\overline\sigma_{i_k} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
we obtain the main result: $$\int \limits_{\overline\sigma}\omega=-\int \limits_{\sigma}\omega$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is subtle. While - for sufficiently regular $g$ - we have

$$\int_{Q^k} g(u_1,u_2,u_3,\dotsc, u_k)\,d\mathbf{u} = \int_{Q^k} g(u_2, u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k)\,d\mathbf{u},\tag{$\ast$}$$

the $u_j$ in the "denominator" of $\dfrac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc, \sigma_{i_k})}{\partial (u_1,\dotsc, u_k)}$ are not arguments of the integrand, they just denote the order of the columns. Maybe a different notation would have prevented the mistake. If we denote the partial derivatives by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$, and still call the argument $\mathbf{u}$, we get

\begin{align}
\int_{\sigma} \omega &= \int_{Q^k} f(\sigma(u_1,\dotsc,u_k))\cdot \frac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial (x_1,\dotsc,x_k)}(u_1,\dotsc,u_k)\,d\mathbf{u}\\
&= \int_{Q^k} f(\sigma(u_2,u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k))\cdot \frac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial (x_1,\dotsc,x_k)}(u_2,u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k)\,d\mathbf{u}\\
&= -\int_{Q^k}  f(\sigma(u_2,u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k))\cdot \frac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial (x_2, x_1,x_3,\dotsc,x_k)}(u_2,u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k)\,d\mathbf{u},
\end{align}

and since the determinant is constant, the latter is

$$-\int_{Q^k}   f(\sigma(u_2,u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k))\cdot \frac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial (x_2, x_1,x_3,\dotsc,x_k)}(u_1,\dotsc,u_k)\,d\mathbf{u} = -\int_{\overline{\sigma}} \omega,$$

as it should be.

If we use the constantness of the determinant and write $A_I$ for the matrix consisting of the rows $i_1,\dotsc, i_k$ of $A$ and analogously for $C$, then we have

\begin{align}
\int_{\sigma} \omega &= \det A_I \int_{Q^k} f(\sigma(u_1,\dotsc,u_k))\,d\mathbf{u}\\
\int_{\overline{\sigma}} \omega &= \det C_I \int_{Q^k} f(\sigma(u_2,u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k))\,d\mathbf{u}
\end{align}

and the assertion follows from $(\ast)$ and $\det C_I = -\det A_I$.

Comment: 1) You denote partial derivatives by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ but components of $\sigma$, namely $\sigma_{i_1}, \sigma_{i_2},\dots$ does not depend on $x_j$. There is no $x_j$'s in my reasonings. And this moment confuses me. 2) Why determinant is constant?

Comment: That's kind of the point, that there are no $x_j$s, to emphasise that the $u_j$ in $\dfrac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc, \sigma_{i_k})}{\partial (u_1,\dotsc, u_k)}$ play a different role than in $f(\sigma(u_1,\dotsc,u_k))$. In the determinant, they're just indices, not arguments. It may have been better to not name them at all and just work with indexed partials, $\partial_j$ denoting the partial derivative with respect to the variable in the $j$-th position, but $\dfrac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc, \sigma_{i_k})}{\partial_1\dotsc\partial_k}$ looks a bit silly.

Comment: The determinant is constant because we're looking at affine maps. With $F(u) = v + A\cdot u$, the Jacobian matrix $J_F$ is constant, $J_F(u) = A$ for all $u$, and so the determinant of the submatrix consisting of rows $i_1,\dotsc,i_k$, $\dfrac{\partial (F_{i_1},\dotsc, F_{i_k})}{\partial (u_1,\dotsc,u_k)}$ is constant, it's the determinant of the constant matrix with entries $m_{r,c} = a_{i_r,c}$.

Comment: But this equality little bit confuses me since $$\int \limits_{\overline \sigma}\omega=\int \limits_{Q^k}f(\overline\sigma(u_1,u_2,\dots, u_k))\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
D_1\overline \sigma_{i_1} & D_2\overline \sigma_{i_1} \cdots & D_k\overline \sigma_{i_1} \\
D_1\overline \sigma_{i_2} & D_2\overline \sigma_{i_2}\cdots & D_k\overline \sigma_{i_2} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
D_1\overline \sigma_{i_k} & D_2\overline \sigma_{i_k}\cdots & D_k\overline \sigma_{i_k} \\
\end{bmatrix}(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_k) d\mathbf{u}$$

Comment: But you wrote that $$\int_{Q^k}   f(\sigma(u_2,u_1,u_3,\dotsc,u_k))\cdot \frac{\partial (\sigma_{i_1},\dotsc,\sigma_{i_k})}{\partial (x_2, x_1,x_3,\dotsc,x_k)}(u_1,\dotsc,u_k)\,d\mathbf{u} = \int_{\overline{\sigma}} \omega,$$ Can you explain why mine expression coincides with your?

Comment: That $\overline{\sigma}(u_1,u_2,\dotsc,u_k) = \sigma(u_2,u_1,\dotsc,u_k)$ is the definition of $\overline{\sigma}$. So all that remains is to see the equality of the second factors. But by the definition of $\overline{\sigma}$, we have $D_1\overline{\sigma}_r = D_2 \sigma_r$ and $D_2\overline{\sigma}_r = D_1\sigma_r$ for all $r$, while for $j > 2$ we have $D_j\overline{\sigma}_r = D_j\sigma_r$ for all $r$. So both matrices are

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix} D_1 \sigma_{i_1} & \dotsc & D_k \sigma_{i_1} \\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ D_1 \sigma_{i_k} & \dotsc & D_k \sigma{i_k}\end{pmatrix}$$ with the first and second columns interchanged. The interchange is only indicated in different ways. So we have (pointwise) equality of the integrands, and hence the integrals are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39062/discussion-between-rfz-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: Dear Daniel! I have added the proof for another case. Can you check it please? Look the EDIT in main post.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Please sorry but can you look at this topic.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766390/affine-chains-from-pma-rudin-confusing-examples Any your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Your proof for the case of swapping $p_0$ and $p_1$ is correct. Neat idea to reduce it to the one-dimensional integral.