# Unit square as union of two simplexes

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

[image]?

If Rudin regarded $\Phi$ as a function of $2$-forms and suppose that $\omega=f(\mathbf{x})dx_{i_1}\land dx_{i_2}$ is $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^m$ then
$$I_{\Phi}(\omega)=\int \limits_{\Phi}\omega=\int \limits_{I^2} f(\Phi(\mathbf{u}))\begin{vmatrix}
D_1\phi_{i_1} & D_2\phi_{i_1} \\
D_1\phi_{i_2} & D_2\phi_{i_2}
\end{vmatrix}(u_1,u_2)d\mathbf{u}=\int \limits_{\sigma_1(Q^2)}+\int \limits_{\sigma_2(Q^2)}$$
Let's take a look at first integral: $$\int \limits_{\sigma_1(Q^2)}f(\Phi(\mathbf{u}))\begin{vmatrix}
D_1\phi_{i_1} & D_2\phi_{i_1} \\
D_1\phi_{i_2} & D_2\phi_{i_2}
\end{vmatrix}(u_1,u_2)d\mathbf{u}$$ Making transform $\mathbf{u}\mapsto \sigma_1(\mathbf{u})$ and since $\sigma_1$ is injective and $C'$-mapping (and it's Jacobian is $1$) then by theorem 10.9 we have $$\int \limits_{Q^2}f(\Phi(\sigma_1(\mathbf{u})))\begin{vmatrix}
D_1\phi_{i_1}\circ \sigma_1 & D_2\phi_{i_1}\circ \sigma_1  \\
D_1\phi_{i_2}\circ \sigma_1 & D_2\phi_{i_2}\circ \sigma_1
\end{vmatrix}(u_1,u_2)d\mathbf{u}$$
But for right application of theorem 10.9 support of integrand must be compact and lies in $\sigma_1(Q^2)$. Right? But we have no information about it.

The second question why $\Phi\circ \sigma_1+\Phi\circ \sigma_2$ is $2$-chain?

Comment: The joys of the higher-dimensional Riemann integral :-/ It's not particularly difficult to generalise theorem 10.9 so that it applies to this situation. But it's probably less work to do it differently. Use 10.25 to see $\int_{\Phi} \omega = \int_{I^2} \omega_{\Phi}$. Let $A = \sigma_1(Q^2)$ and $B = \sigma_2(Q^2)$. It's not hard to see that $\int_{I^2} \omega_{\Phi} = \int_A \omega_{\Phi} + \int_B \omega_{\Phi}$. That $\int_A \omega_{\Phi} = \int_{\sigma_1} \omega_{\Phi}$ is immediate from the definition. That $\int_B \omega_{\Phi} = \int_{\sigma_2} \omega_{\Phi}$ requires a wee bit of work,

Comment: but since the map $\sigma_2$ is very simple, it's not hard to verify either, going through the definition of the Riemann integral. Since $\Phi$ is differentiable, the map $\Phi \circ \sigma_i$ is a differentiable $2$-simplex for $i \in \{1,2\}$. Thus $\Phi \circ \sigma_1 + \Phi \circ \sigma_2$ is a differentiable $2$-chain.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Let me ask you some questions on your answer. 1) How you use theorem 10.25? How did you get $I^2$? 2) Also $\int \limits_{A}\omega_{\Phi}=\int \limits_{\sigma_1}\omega_{\Phi}$ how follows from definition?

Comment: @DanielFischer, Can you help me please with my questions, please? I would be very thankful for your help!

Comment: @DanielFischer, Can you answer please to my above questions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Rudin at hand, but in the hope a picture is worth a thousand words:
You presumably have a standard $2$-simplex $Q^{2}$, and are partitioning the unit square $I^{2}$ as shown:

[image: An integral over the square as a sum of integrals over two simplices]

1. If $\omega$ is a $2$-form defined on the image $\Phi(I^{2})$, the integral breaks into two summands, one for each simplex, each an integral over the *standard* simplex.
2. A $2$-chain is a formal (finite) integer linear combination of images of the standard $2$-simplex, i.e., an element of the free Abelian group on the space of $2$-simplices. The diagram should make obvious the sense in which
   $$
   \Phi(I^{2}) = \Phi \circ \sigma_{1}(Q^{2}) + \Phi \circ \sigma_{2}(Q^{2})
   $$
   as $2$-chains.

Comment: Thanks for answer but your answer seems little bit weird to me. 2) Rudin does not define chain as formal (finite) integer linear combination of images of standard simplexes. Image must be class of $C''$. 1) Integral is over $I^2$ but when you break into two integrals you must make transform to get what wee need.