# Stokes' Theorem from PMA Rudin. Confusing moment with simplex

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I am reading the proof of Stokes' theorem from PMA Rudin but one moment seems to very weird. [image]

Why Rudin considers the case when $\sigma=[0,\mathbf{e}_1,\dots, \mathbf{e}_k]$? After all $\sigma$ may take the form $[\mathbf{p}_0, \mathbf{p}_1,\dots, \mathbf{p}_k]$.

Can anyone explain this important moment?

I can't understand it by myself.

Comment: He explains it in the following lines. With theorems 10.22 and 10.25, you can pull back the general case to that special case, so it suffices to prove it for the standard simplex.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Sorry but how theorems 10.22 and 10.25 can be used? In What sense?

Comment: Pull back via $T$. By 10.22, we have $(d\omega)_T = d(\omega_T)$. By 10.25, we have $\int_{\Phi} d\omega = \int_{\sigma} (d\omega)_T$ and $\int_{\partial \Phi} \omega = \int_{T(\partial \sigma)} \omega = \int_{\partial \sigma} \omega_T$.

Comment: I understood that moment. But I am interesting why he considers the case when simplex have form $\sigma=[0,\mathbf{e}_1,..,\mathbf{e}_k]$ but not some $\sigma=[\mathbf{p}_0,\mathbf{p}_1,..,\mathbf{p}_k]$.

Comment: The main question is: Why we can represent $\Phi$ as $T\circ \sigma$ where $\sigma=[0,e_1,\dots, e_k]$. That worries me :/

Comment: Because the affine simplex $[0,e_1,\dotsc,e_k]$ is given by the identity map. The set it covers is just $Q^k$, and by definition of a differentiable $k$-simplex $\Phi$ is given by a differentiable map $T$ defined in some open neighbourhood of $Q^k$. $\Phi = T\lvert_{Q^k}$, so $\Phi = \Phi \circ \operatorname{id}_{Q^k} = T\circ \operatorname{id}_{Q^k} = T\circ\sigma$, since $\sigma = \operatorname{id}_{Q^k}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39443/discussion-between-rfz-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: @DanielFischer, Since $\Phi$ is oriented $k$-simplex of class $C''$ in open set $V\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ $\Rightarrow$ by definition 10.30 exists some mapping $T$ from $E$ into $V\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. domain of $T$ is some open set $E$. Also by definition 10.30 $\Phi$ has domain $Q^k$. Hence $\Phi=T\mid_{Q^k}$.
Note that $Q^k\subset E$ because otherwise $\Phi=T\mid_{Q^k}$ would be false. Are my reasonings true?

Comment: That's right so far.

Comment: Hello Daniel! Can you please help with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777806/definition-of-exact-form?

Comment: I think rudin utilizes the fact that compact convex open sets are homeomorphic to each other, so that open set E can be pulled back to open set around origin.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Could you help please with this topic? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178128/the-erdos-and-turan-function/2178299#2178299