# Definition of exact form

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

[image]

That's the definition of *exact form* in $E$. But if we look at the definition 10.18 we see that $\lambda \in C'$ but Rudin skip this condition.

Can anyone please explain this moment

Comment: It would have been better to be explicit about the differentiability assumptions, I think, but Rudin left them implicit here. He's talking about $d\lambda$, so $\lambda$ has to be a form for which $d\lambda$ makes sense. I don't think Rudin has extended the notion to more general forms in the book, so $\lambda$ would need to be continuously differentiable.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Hello! Can you help please with this? I am dealing with this couple days and no ideas. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779261/circle-as-oriented-1-simplex-and-its-boundary

Comment: @DanielFischer, I would so grateful for your help, Daniel!