# Circle as oriented $1$-simplex and it's boundary

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

Let $\gamma(t)=(r\cos t, r\sin t)$ where $r>0$ is fixed and $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Rudin write that it's an *"oriented 1-simplex"*. Also he states that $$\partial \gamma=0.$$
Let $T(u)=(r\cos u,r\sin u)$ and $\sigma=[0,2\pi]$. We see that $\sigma(u)=2\pi u$ for $u\in Q^1=[0,1]$. We see that $T\in C''$ and $T\circ \sigma(u)$ for $u\in Q^1$ is circle with radius $r>0$ on the plane. Hence by definition 10.30 $\Phi=T\circ \sigma$ is oriented 1-simplex. Right? By definition of boundary $$\partial \gamma=\partial (T\circ \sigma)=T(\partial \sigma)=T([2\pi]-[0])=?$$

How to show that above expression is zero?

P.S. It's from Rudin PMA example 10.36.

Can anyone please help with this moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $T(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is a $k$-chain (here $k = 0$), we have

$$T([2\pi] - [0]) = T([2\pi]) - T([0]).$$

For the given $T$, we have

$$T([2\pi]) = [(r,0)] = T([0]),$$

and thus

$$\partial \gamma = [(r,0)] - [(r,0)] = 0.$$

Generally, if $\alpha \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a (sufficiently smooth) curve, we have $\partial \alpha = [\alpha(b)] - [\alpha(a)]$. If the curve is closed, that reduces to $0$.

Comment: Let me ask you one question: How you get that $T([2\pi] - [0]) = T([2\pi]) - T([0])?$ Are you using formula $(88)$?

Comment: If you are using $(88)$ we get the following: $T([2\pi]-[0])=T([2\pi])+T(-[0])$. Why $T(-[0])=-T([0])$?

Comment: Before posting this topic I also have the above assumption. But i was not sure on its validity :( I don't know how to prove it strictly. Can you show it please?

Comment: It's $(88)$ together with 10.26, and most importantly that it's the only thing that makes the theory work. For affine chains, you get it from $(82)$ and $(81)$, I'm not entirely sure whether you can directly deduce it from 10.30 for differentiable $0$-simplices. For $k \geqslant 1$, you get $T(-\sigma) = -T(\sigma)$ directly from the definitions in 10.30, So if one can't deduce it for differentiable $0$-simplices, one still has the argument that it's the only thing that is consistent with a) the case $k \geqslant 1$, b) the affine case. And, as said, it's the only thing that "works".

Comment: That chapter isn't one of Rudin's best, I have to say. It would have been better to introduce chains as "formal linear combinations (with integer coefficients)". That makes things like this much more transparent (since one would have defined $T(\sum c_k \sigma_k) = \sum c_k T(\sigma_k)$).

Comment: I need some moment to realize your comment. First of all, you write that it's follows from (88)+10.26. Then you write that it follows from (82)+(81). But this steps seems to me weird :/

Comment: You think that the best way is accept your definition and skip it's rigorous proof?

Comment: I guess that it's rigorous proof very hard.

Comment: If $\sigma_1=-\sigma_2$ then $\sigma_1+\sigma_2=0$. Hence $T(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)=T(\sigma_1)+T(\sigma_2)=T(0)$ by (88). Why $T(0)=0$?

Comment: $(82)$ and $(81)$ deal with the affine case. The proof of 10.27 explicitly mentions the case $k = 0$,  so in the affine case, everything's covered. But $T$ is not an affine map. If you look at definition 10.30, it's fine for $k \geqslant 1$ since then you can get the appropriate orientation by permuting vertices, so it's sufficient to look at the maps $T\circ \sigma$. But that doesn't quite work for $0$-simplices, since an oriented $0$-simplex is not and cannot be represented as only a map, you need an explicit sign for the orientation. $T \circ (\varepsilon [p])$ doesn't make sense,

Comment: since $\varepsilon [p]$ isn't a map. One has to define what that should mean. I may have overlooked something, but it seems that that fell under the rug and Rudin didn't define it anywhere [at least not explicitly]. To prove things about anything, one needs a definition. I happen to know how it's defined from other sources, so I have reason to be confident that that's the right definition beyond 1) it being consistent with a) the affine case, b) the higher-dimensional case and 2) any other definition makes things break when $0$-chains are involved.

Comment: Once you have a clear definition of $T\circ \sigma$ for an oriented $0$-simplex $\sigma$, it's not hard at all to prove it, it follows directly from the definition. The weak point in this chapter is, I think, that Rudin didn't want to get too abstract and introduce chain groups (as formal linear combinations [with integer coefficients] of oriented simplices, modulo equivalence) and tried to stick to "collections of simplices" as chains, which resulted in the case of oriented differentiable $0$-simplices hanging in the air a bit.

Comment: Concerning "Why $T(0) = 0$", recall that a chain $\Psi$ is $0$ if $\int_{\Psi} \omega = 0$ for all forms $\omega$. Then, by 10.25 we have $$\int_{T\Psi} \omega = \int_{\Psi} \omega_T = 0$$ for all $\omega$, and thus $T\Psi = 0$.

Comment: What book you can recommend as good book of vector analysis and diff. forms?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't recommend one. If you can read German, then I can say that Otto Forster's _Analysis 3_ isn't bad. But what few books I know, none of them is really convincing in that department.