# The Erdos and Turan function

Tags: ramsey-theory

This is the excerpt from the book "Ramsey theory on the integers".
There are some confusing moments and I would be thankful if anybody helps me to grasp it.[image]

The definition of $\nu_k(n)$ I understood. In the second paragraph author proves that $\nu_3(8)\leq 4$.

I have the following questions:

1) When considers the case $|T|\geq 5$ why in that case we are guaranteed to have a monochromatic 3-term AP?

2) Why he also working on the case $|T|\geq 6$? He already had worked on the case $|T|\geq 5$?!

3) Why he separately examining the case $|T|=5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will admit I do not fully understand this paragraph ... indeed I would have written ... There are $56$ subset of cardinality $5$ in $[1,8]$; I leave as an exercise to the reader to write them down & confirm that each one contains an arithemetic progression of length $3$. Hence blah blah.

This does not answer any of your 3 Questions.

1) This is a statement of what will be established & at this stage it is a claim.

2) He establishes that it suffices only to look at the case  $ \mid T \mid =5$ because a larger cardinality would contain this case.

3) I have addressed in my answer to 2).

Comment: Dear Donald! I suppose that I understood you right now after reading your  post. As I realized 1) it is just claim(statement) which validity he shows in 2) and 3). Firstly, he shows that if $|T|\geq 6$ then it always contains AP. Secondly, he considers the case $|T|=5$. Right?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, You are right, & we are now sure that $\nu_{3}(8)=4$. Good luck mastering the rest of the good Mr Ramsey's Book.

Comment: One more question: In the case of $|T|=5$ (since $|R|=3$) why he considers only these $R$ which contain monochromatic AP? What about if $R$ does not contain AP? For example, $R=\{1,2,7\}$?!

Comment: @RFZ This is the killer question : Why when looking for a maximal cardinality set that avoids an arithemetic progression we need only consider those sets whose complement does contain an arithmetic progression? I did consider this before answering your question & believe me if I had cracked that nut I would have given the explanation in my answer. I will continue to think about this & let you know if I ever find the reason.

Comment: Thank you! Would be very thankful if you can give answer in the soon future!

Comment: Hello, dear Donald! If you recall we were talking about this topic about one year ago. I came back to this topic and have understood your post but except one moment: When the author considers the case $|T|=5, |R|=3$. If $R$ contains the monochromatic 3 arithmetic progression (AP) then $T$ also contains 3 AP. What if $R$ does not contains monochromatic 3-term progression? How to complete this case?

Comment: If you have any comment about that it would be amazing!

Comment: @RFZ Sorry for taking my time getting back to you. These Ramsey number/ optimal configuartion style problems are facsinating but also devilishly difficult. This is a topic I often mean to return to, but I have been side tracked by Stirling numbers & combinatorial objects related to hierarchical clusterings. Thank you for returning this topic to my attention. $\ddot \smile$